# PHP SQL: Inserting or Updating from array with different tables, columns, primaries and keys

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I dont even know if this is possible, but i'm hoping that it is. I've created a script that creates a form on a page. When submitted the script validates all fields in the form, and should insert the content into a database.

The fields in the form can have different tables, columns, primary keys and key.

This is an example:

```
 'biler_url' => 
array (size=19)
  'fs_inputs_type' => string 'url' (length=3)
  'fs_inputs_name' => string 'biler_url' (length=9)
  'fs_inputs_table' => string 'biler' (length=5)
  'fs_inputs_placeholder' => string 'Url' (length=3)
  'fs_inputs_value' => string '' (length=0)
  'fs_inputs_label' => string '' (length=0)
  'fs_inputs_set_class' => string 'url_class' (length=9)
  'fs_inputs_set_id' => string 'url_id' (length=6)
  'fs_inputs_id' => int 1
  'fs_inputs_primary' => string 'biler_id' (length=8)
  'fs_inputs_selector' => string '$_GET["id"]' (length=11)
  'fs_inputs_element' => string 'input' (length=5)
  'fs_inputs_title' => string 'Biler Url' (length=9)
  'fs_inputs_SQL_type' => string 'UPDATE' (length=6)
  'fs_inputs_standard_value' => null
  'fs_inputs_filter' => string 'FILTER_VALIDATE_URL' (length=19)
  'fs_inputs_required' => string 'true' (length=4)
  'fs_inputs_min_length' => null
  'fs_inputs_max_length' => int 50
```

So this inputs SQL should look like this:

```
UPDATE biler SET 'biler_url' = $_POST['biler_url'] WHERE biler_id = $_GET['id'];
```

My biggest problem is inserting since all values would be inserted individually, since i dont know where the previous values belonging to the same table were inserted.

Comment: Can you insert tablewise. & save last insert id in some variable. Use this as primary key to insert into next table and so on.

Comment: Is there some sort of function in mysqli that could give me the last id?

Comment: I could create an array where the key is the table and value is the last id

Comment: `mysqli_insert_id()` will give you the last inserted ID.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas,

You are not clear on the update/new part.
When you create your form, you must be aware if you are displaying an existing row in some table, or creating a new one.
I always send along in my forms something with an instruction, something like this:
(I assume bilerid is the primary key of your table)

for new:

```
<form action="..." Method="POST" name="myForm">
 <input type="hidden" name="theAction" value="new">
 <input type="hidden" name="bilerid" value="-1">
 ....rest of the form here...
</form>

<form action="..." Method="POST" name="myForm">
 <input type="hidden" name="theAction" value="update">
 <input type="hidden" name="bilerid" value="1435">
 ....rest of the form here...
</form>
```

Then upon receiving, you just check $_POST["theAction"] for new/update and handle it with an insert or update in your SQL.

Note that you should also check if the passed bilerid "belongs" to the person posting this form. You don't want people fiddling with id they do not own. (But I am not sure if that applies to your situation)